# Can't connect unsecured wifi from Wicd or terminal

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp, wicd

I can connect without issue to `WPA` networks, but if I am somewhere like a hotel and try to connect to an unsecured WiFi, things hang at the `DHCP` part and I don't get an `IP` assigned.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and my Wifi is on `eth1`

Wicd, hangs at the getting IP address part. I've tried also (as root)

```
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig eth1 down
dhclient -r eth1
iwconfig eth1 essid AP_Name
ifconfig eth1 up
dhclient eth1
```

this just hangs at the `dhclient eth1` request until I `Ctrl+C` it.